# автоматическое размонтирование LUKS диска

Tags: linux, администрирование, шифрование, linux-mint

Linux Mint 21.1. Один из разделов зашифрован, при необходимости монтируется скриптом с ручным вводом пароля:

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdb2 sdb2
sudo mount /dev/mapper/sdb2 "$HOME/sdb2"
```

Хочется его размонтировать по таймауту (неактивности, отсутствии доступа). Пока нагуглилось такое, заменить `mount` на

```
sudo systemd-mount --timeout-idle-sec=300s --automount=true /dev/mapper/sdb2 "$HOME/sdb2"
```

В теории должно работать, на практике нет, не размонтируется по таймауту :(

---

Как выяснилось, на самом деле размонтируется. Но при этом automount-сервис остаётся активным. И даже при указании ключа `-u` (Stop the mount and automount units corresponding to the specified mount points) созданные им .mount и .automount юниты остаются в `/run/systemd/transient`. А поскольку сам LUKS-диск остаётся открытым в `/dev/mapper`, то при любом обращении к каталогу `Where` диск снова монтируется, причём мгновенно, без запроса пароля.

Появилась такая мысль: после монтирования запустить каку-нибудь утилитку, которая мониторила бы активность в каталоге. И если время простоя больше заданного интервала, вызывала бы скриптик, который корректно размонтирует и закрывает LUKS-диск. Вопрос: какую утилиту? От неё требуется только одно: получать время последней активности в каталоге. В принципе и сам могу набросать (`fcntl( dir_fd, F_NOTIFY, ...)`, но не хочется изобретать велосипед.